# ternary operator in razor view returns code as string

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to format data but I get wrong results, how can I fix that?

```
 <div>
        @string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.Customer.State) ? @Model.Customer.Country : @string.Format("{0}, {1}", Model.Customer.Country, Model.Customer.State);
    </div>
```

It returns:

```
True ? French: French, ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add some brackets so it is treated as one single statement block...

```
<div>
    @(string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.Customer.State) ? Model.Customer.Country : string.Format("{0}, {1}", Model.Customer.Country, Model.Customer.State));
</div>
```

Comment: ah... I wrapped the single statements and it did not work Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have to wrap the entire condition with brackets:

```
<div>
    @(string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.Customer.State) ? Model.Customer.Country : string.Format("{0}, {1}", Model.Customer.Country, Model.Customer.State))
</div>
```